# Format and limit php decimal places

Tags: php

I'm trying to format an integer with 5 digits using php with number format plus I'm not getting the result waiting.

Example: 35914
Expected result: 35.91

Note that I pretending limits to only 2 decimal places after the point.

My attempts:

```
<?php

$number = 35914;

echo $english_format_number = number_format($number)."<p>";
// 35,914

// Notação Francesa
echo $nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ')."<p>";
// 35 914,00


// Notação Inglesa com separador de milhar
echo $english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '')."<p>";
// 35914.00

?>
```

Comment: But 35.91 isn't 35914 formatted differently. It's a completely different number.

Comment: Do you want a *decimal* or a *thousands separator*? Because they are entirely different things.

Answer (score -1):

I do not get exactly your problem, but I would recommend to have a look on String functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).

Using the `str_split` function, for example, we can transform the input number in the expected output.

```
<?php
    $input = 35914;

    $editedNumber = str_split($input,2);
    $editedNumber = $editedNumber[0] . "." . $editedNumber[1];

    echo $editedNumber; // 35.91
?>
```